# How to list all jobs and execution accounts in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, jobs, account

Some of the jobs in my SQL Servers are running under personal accounts. I would want to get a list of all jobs and their execution accounts so I can remove the personal account and use service account. Would someone please tell me how to do it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This query below should display the job name & the owner account.

```
select s.name,l.name
from  msdb..sysjobs s 
      left outer join master.sys.syslogins l on s.owner_sid = l.sid
```

Comment: Is owner account executed account? Because one account can create the job but that job can run as on another account. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT  s.name , SUSER_SNAME(s.owner_sid) AS owner
FROM    msdb..sysjobs s 
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Please see my commend above to Mike. Thank you.